# What's the easiest way to get current time into a field in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm recording results into an Excel spreadsheet, and I want to record the time I enter the results.  In Notepad, one can simply press F6 to get the current time stamp.  Is there a simple/easy way to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about these:

- For the current date: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>
- For the current time: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>
- For the current date and time: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just add `=NOW()` in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

There are shortcuts for date (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) and time (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>)

see also: [**Insert the current date and time in a cell**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP030561071033.aspx)

For other language versions of Excel the shortcuts are a little different. For the german version the shortcuts are <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>